# How to send subscribe email in a custom module in magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, module, email

I have created a custom module, need to send a newsletter subscription email to the consumer in magento2.2.5?
Refer screenshot

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to customer  to be subcribe?

Comment: Yes, I want the customer to be subscribed to the newletter.